# C# MySql funktion (command string in, return reader)

Tags: c#, mysql

I've written a function to perform MySQL statements. In this function I give in a statement and get back the MySqlDataReader, but the problem is my function do not close the connection. After a short while of using the Programm, it crashs because the new connection can't be open. This is the error i got by trying open the new connection:

> error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior
>   to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred
>   because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was
>   reached.

My code look like this:
MySQL Class:

```
class mySql
{

    string cs = "server=123.123.123.123;" +
                "uid=abcabc;" +
                "pwd=123456;" +
                "database=overflow_test;";

    private MySqlConnection conn_f()     // create a Connection
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;

        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();

        conn.ConnectionString = cs;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public MySqlDataReader CMD_f(string comand) //execute SQL Command
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        MySqlConnection conn = conn_f();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandText = comand;
        cmd.Prepare();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return rdr;
    }
}
```

and an example how i use it Main Class

```
class main{
mySql DB = new mySql();
public void main(){
MySqlDataReader rdr = DB.CMD_f("SELECT * FROM tbl_kategorie");
        int i = 0;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string str = rdr.GetString(1);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
}
```

Has someone an Idea to solve the Problem.
 Sincere regards LFS96 (Fabian Harmsen)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the inbalance in the code. The `CMD_f` method creates a connection, but doesn't take responsibility for it. You should rather make the method that creates the connection public, so that you can take responsibility for it in the code that can close it.

That's a bigger change, so first let's look at a smaller change to fix the code.

The data reader should expose the data connection as the `Connection` property. I don't see that in the documentation, so it's possible that it doesn't, but the data readers in the .NET framework does.

If the property is exposed, then you can make a quick fix to make the code work with minimal change:

```
MySqlDataReader rdr = DB.CMD_f("SELECT * FROM tbl_kategorie");
int i = 0;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    string str = rdr.GetString(1);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
rdr.Close();
rdr.Connection.Close();
```

---

If you make the `conn_f` method public and don't call it in the `CMD_f` method, you can write much more robust code, that never leaves a connection or data reader hanging even if there is an error. That's a bigger change in the code, but definitely worth the effort when you have time to implement and test it. Using a `using` block to make sure that the objects are always disposed correctly makes the code much more resilient:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = DB.conn_f()) {
  using (MySqlDataReader rdr = DB.CMD_f(conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_kategorie")) {
    int i = 0;
    while (rdr.Read()) {
      string str = rdr.GetString(1);
      Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: Identifiers in C# tend to be descriptive. I suggest names like `DB.CreateConnection` and `DB.ExecuteReader` rather than `DB.conn_f` and `DB.CMD_f`.